# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given

Tags: laravel, json, angular, laravel-8

Estoy generando un JSON con cierta información para luego pasar ésta a mi API y de esta manera poder ejecutar una prueba de LogIn, pero sucede que al momento en el que el JSON se pasa a la API pude notar que el JSON se genera con 2 comillas que se hallan fuera de las llaves {}, luciendo entonces de esta manera:

```
XHRPOSThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 871ms]
    
json{"userId":"","tipo_documento":"","nombres":"","apellidos":"","direccion":"","correo_electronico":"prueba@hotmail.com","contrasena":"Prueba123","telefono":"","celular":"","tipo_Usuario":"","ultima_act":""}    --->""<---
```

Las comillas que se hallan señaladas con dos flechas son los elementos que menciono que se generan y por ende no me permiten validar el JSON en la API elaborada, haciendo así que la API me devuelva este error:

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\nicod\OneDrive\CEA\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 261

Agradecería me pudieran brindar una ayuda, gracias!

Método del servicio en Angular que establece conexión con el API:

```
signup(user: any, getToken = null): Observable<any>{
    if(getToken != null){
        user.getToken = true;
        console.log(user.getToken);
    }

    let jsonString = JSON.stringify(user);
    let params = "json"+jsonString;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    return this._http.post(this.url+'/login', params, {headers: headers});
}
```

Componente que recibe los datos para insertarlos sobre el modelo y según la respuesta del servicio conocer el estado de la petición:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public user: User;
  public status: string;

  constructor( private _userService: UserService ) {

    this.user = new User('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '');
    this.status = '';

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(form: any){
    this._userService.signup(this.user).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        this.status = 'error';
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
      )
   }
}
```

Parte del método del controlador en laravel que me da el error debido al campo vacío dentro de las `""` fuera de las `{}`, El error claramente se evidencia con el *Validator*.

```
$jwtValidator = new \JwtAuth();
        
    $jsonData = $request->input('json', null);
    $paramsObj = json_decode($jsonData);
    $paramsArray= json_decode($jsonData, true);

    $validateData = \Validator::make($paramsArray,[
        'correo_electronico' => ['required', 'email'],
        'contrasena' => ['required']
    ]);

    if($validateData->fails()){
        $signUp = array(
            'status' => 'Error',
            'code' => 404,
            'message' => 'El usuario no se ha podido identificar',
            'errors' => $validate->errors()
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular se encarga de convertir los objetos a JSON. Solo aségurate de que el objeto tenga la estructura correcta.

```
signup(user: any, getToken = null): Observable<any>{
        if(getToken != null){
            user.getToken = true;
            console.log(user.getToken);

        }
        // no es necesario usar stringify
        let params = {json : user};
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        return this._http.post(this.url+'/login', params, {headers: headers});

}
```

Comment: Jumm muchas gracias por el comentario, sin embargo, he seguido revisando quitando así el método de la validación en la API y la respuesta que me devuelve el servicio ahora es: message: "Trying to get property 'contrasena' of non-object"